# Package translation files not working - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use language files inside a custom package.
I followed this documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/master/packages#translations, but it's not working and only outputs Namespace::file.key as string.

There is no error. What could I have done wrong?

Loaded as:

```
$this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__.'/resources/lang', 'TranslatableRoute');
```

Used as:

```
trans('TranslatableRoute::routes.create')
```

My path structure is as follows:

`packages
 - doitonlinemedia
 - - translatableroutes
 - - - src
 - - - - TranslatableRoute.php
 - - - - TranslatableRoutesServiceProvider.php
 - - - - resources
 - - - - - lang
 - - - - - - en
 - - - - - - - routes.php`

Routes.php contains:

```
return [
    'create' => 'new',
    'edit' => 'edit'
];
```

Found something strange. When I dump `$this->app['translator']` it contains:

```
array:1 [
    "TranslatableRoute" => array:1 [
      "routes" => array:1 [
        "en" => []
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

But shouldn't it be:

```
array:1 [
    "TranslatableRoute" => array:1 [
      "en" => array:1 [
        "routes" => []
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

**EDIT**

When I'm adding the language files with loadTranslationFrom, it calls addNamespace in vendor/laravel/Translation/FileLoader.php after that `$this->hints` is filled. But as soon as I want to call it this function in the same file is trigger: `loadNamespaced()` in this function `$this->hint`s is empty again. Seems like some bug.

Comment: What's your directory structure? Is the `resources/lang` directory relative to the service provider you are loading the translations from?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, but I think I'm using a wrong approach to this problem, but for now it is fixed.

I'm making a package that is called inside the routes.php file. With some static functions. It seems this is loaded before it boots the package. It is registered, but not booted yet. So I had to add the language files manually by calling in side the package code:

```
\App::make('translator')->addNamespace('TranslatableRoute', __DIR__.'/resources/lang');
```

I guess I need to load my package as some sort of Facade Controller. Not sure how to that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and couldn't figure it out. I ended up changing the namespace I was assigning to the translations and it works now. I don't know why, maybe it was overwriting the namespace to my views, but with a unique namespace it seems to be working.